# Too many values to unpack with for loop

Tags: linux, pycharm, python-3.7

Well I was typing this

```
def read(dictionary):
    a = open("DictionnaireAges.txt")
    for key,value in a:
       dictionary[key]=value
    return dictionary
a={}
b=read(a)
print(b)
```

But I got this:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I'm pretty sure it's in the **for** loop
I also doubt it's because I put a file in the loop
Any help will be apreciated!
 ( ͡❛ ͜ʖ ͡❛)
I'm on linux operating system and working on pycharm©

Comment: `a` is not a `dict`

Comment: The for loop will return a line at a time from the file, not a key and value.  Also, `read` is the name of a method in python, so naming your own function read is not good.

Comment: well in pycharm, it is not counted as a method. And I tried ``` dict(a) ``````but another error happend so no either!